# Use of "the Earth" or Earth?

Tags: grammar, orthography, capitalization

I have a sentence where I'm unsure about my grammar when discussing planets:

"Branch Technology is revolutionizing the use of 3-D printing to create architectural elements and structures that will enable new home designs not only for Earth but maybe even for the Moon and Mars."

Is this grammar and capitalization correct usage? I always get stuck on "the earth" or just "Earth."

Comment: I believe you should add "the" before planets' names. But I don't know whether native speaker would use Capitalization or not.

Comment: In your specific example context, the article is entirely optional before ***Earth*** (but *required* before ***Moon***, so some writers might be more inclined to include it, if only for "stylistic consistency").

Comment: @神秘德里克 no, we never add "the" before planet names other than the Earth. We use "the" before the Sun and the Moon, and other objects like the asteroid belt, the Kuiper belt, the Oort cloud. We capitalise all proper nouns (i.e. an official name for a particular thing), but not "moon" (etc) when we're talking about a generic thing like the moons of Jupiter.